# React Native for Web: Invariant Violation: "cursor" is not a valid style property

Tags: react-native, cursor, react-native-web, react-native-stylesheet

We are using React Native for Web so we do need to be able to modify the cursor if it is in the web but I imagine since there is no cursor on mobile this is an issue with React Native.

How can we allow cursor for at least the web part?

Example:

```
export default StyleSheet.create<Style>({
  .modalContent {

    cursor: "pointer",

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer from [jchook](https://github.com/jchook) on [this GitHub post](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/506#issuecomment-1120465793).

You can use the RN Platform to detect if it is web, and then it will allow you to use the cursor stylesheet attribute.

> ```
> import { Platform } from 'react-native'
>
> export default StyleSheet.create<Style>({
>  .modalContent {
>
>    ...Platform.select({
>      web: {
>        cursor: 'default',
>      },
>    }),
>
>  }
> });
> ```